# Failed to bounce to type firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3SQg.png)

I have data like above im trying write POJO class for that but it makes

```
01-18 21:02:08.101  28838-28838/thamarai.techundefined.com E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: thamarai.techundefined.com, PID: 28838
    com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
            at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
            at net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.ProcessImages$2.onDataChange(ProcessImages.java:144)
            at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:53)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.ProcessImages$RetriveUserData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
            at [Source: java.io.StringReader@41c63110; line: 1, column: 2]
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:984)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
            at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
            at net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.ProcessImages$2.onDataChange(ProcessImages.java:144)
            at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:53)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my code

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               Log.i("FireBase", "snapshot  " + snapshot);
                    RetriveUserData data = snapshot.getValue(RetriveUserData.class);
                    Log.i("FireBase", "Data  " + data.getAPIkey());

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.i("FireBase", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
});
```

here is POJO

```
public class RetriveUserData {
        private String fullName;
        private String apikey;

        public RetriveUserData() {
            // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        public String getAPIkey() {
            return apikey;
        }

    }
```

> Update

here is json what im getting (logged)

```
DataSnapshot { key = 8c73191e-ba59-417a-b8ae-a5fed541c761, value = {fullName=Thamaraiselvam, apikey=sfsdfsdjfosf} }
```

looks like im doing small problem but do not know where it lies.

Comment: That stack trace is incomplete. Please add the entir stack trace, because usually there more exceptions and those indicate the actual cause. My initial guess though is that RetriveUserData is an inner class, in which case you need to mark it as static.

Comment: Please add the actual JSON (instead of a link to a screenshot of it), the minimal code (right now we're missing what the `ref` points to) and the complete stack trace of the error you get. Without those I vote to close, because we're missing an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen have added full trace please check it and added json also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.ProcessImages$RetriveUserData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

From this it seems that you've nested the `RetriveUserData` inside your `ProcessImages` class. In that case Java adds an implicit reference to the outer class to `RetriveUserData`. Since you're not storing that reference in Firebase, it complains about not finding it.

To get rid of this error message, mark `RetriveUserData` as static. This tells Java to not generate the reference:

```
public static class RetriveUserData {
```